# handling concurrency in cron php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, jobs

I am setting up a cron job that executes a script page.php every minute
I wanted to know about the concurrency.
The script it self take 15 minutes to complete, so how the cron will run?

```
Lets take a time frame of 15 minutes, how many crons will run in that time? 1 or 15?

will cron runs till its completion or it can be interrupted?

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start a php script via cron it will run until it finishes or the execution time is exceeded.
The system will always start a new instance of the script whether the last script is still running or not.

If you know that the script is running a long time you should set up a bash script that checks if a script is already running and only start the php script if this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Cron doesn't handle concurrency for you - your script must do so.

Turns out, this is quite easy, as there is a trivial PHP operation, that is atomic: `unlink()`.

We tend to use it this way:

- a global flag file enables the script
- The main cron job does nothing but touch a timer flag file
- Every minute, another cron job starts the worker script
- This worker script tries `unlink()` on the global flag file
- If it does not suceed (result evaluates to false), it quits (This makes sure, only one instance runs at a time)
- This worker script tries `unlink()` on the timer flag file
- If it does not suceed (result evaluates to false), it `touch()`es the global flag file and quits (This makes sure, one cron run starts at most one instance)
- Now it runs
- after finishing, it `touch()`es the global flag file to restart the cycle

This way, cron runs, that would result in concurrency, are left out in a loggable way.

Comment: that wasn't my question at all

Comment: You might consider editing your question to explain it a bit better - maybe I am not the only one misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 0):

it depends in your scheduled task/cron settings. You can configure to launch 15 times your PHP script, or launch it when the previous job is done.
Your scheduled task/cron can be interrupted by it self, by an external signal or also by the configuration you made in scheduled task/cron (stop job if it is not finished in N minutes...)

Hope that helps :)